# После компиляции кода не выводит текст на консоль

Tags: java

подскажите в чем моя ошибка?  (Код компилируется, но выводит пустую строку на консоль). Хотел бы вывести на консоль товар в зависимости от введённого номера с клавиатуры. Можно ли реализовать данный код через switch case?

```
public class Demo1 {

public void baskTovar(String ... katal){
    System.out.println(" Товары в корзине :");

    if ("1".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Штаны (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("2".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Штаны (желтого цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("3".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Майка (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("4".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Майка (черного цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("5".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Галстук (розового цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("6".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Галстук (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("7".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Часы (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    } else if ("8".equals(katal)) {
        System.out.println("Товар Часы (серого цвета) добавлен в корзину");
    }


}
```

}

```
public class Demo2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String katal = null;
    Demo1 demo1 = new Demo1();
    katal= buf.readLine();
    demo1.baskTovar(katal);
}
```

}

Comment: О боже мои глаза.  Три точки вам зачем? Если вы хотели использовать массив аргументов   то почему не перебирает его как массив , а просто проверяете аргумент как строку

Comment: И вы вызываете потом эту функцию,  а в нее так и ничего не передали

Comment: а в яве switch уже отменили или и не было никогда?

Comment: И для таких задач сканер лучше используйте

Comment: Извиняюсь, только обучаюсь. Это часть кода(пытаюсь сократить основной код), хотел в этот метод передать значения введение с клавиатуры, которые в дальнейшем выведут мне соответствующие строки. Хотел бы уточнить, как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема исходного кода в том, что строки-константы `"1", "2", .. "8"` сравниваются с **массивом строк** `katal`.

Следует либо заменить тип аргумента в методе `baskTovar` на обычную строку, либо проитерировать по массиву.

Также вместо множественных операторов `if/else if` следовало воспользоваться оператором / выражением `switch`, предусмотрев при этом печать сообщения, когда ни одно из условий не выполнилось:

```java
public void baskTovar(String katal){
    System.out.println(" Товары в корзине :");

    String message = switch(katal) {
        case "1" -> "Товар Штаны (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "2" -> "Товар Штаны (желтого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "3" -> "Товар Майка (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "4" -> "Товар Майка (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "5" -> "Товар Галстук (розового цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "6" -> "Товар Галстук (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "7" -> "Товар Часы (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "8" -> "Товар Часы (серого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        default -> "Неизвестный код: " + katal;
    };

    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Изначально пытался через switch, но не вышло. А если необходимо добавить сразу несколько товаров, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: В вашем случае проще всего обернуть в бесконечный цикл, чтоб после добавления опять шло добавление    . Чтоб  выйти из цикла пишите условие с break  и каждый раз выводите сообщение типа :"чтоб выйти введите букву E " или т.п.

Comment: Либо парсить строку по определённым правилам и уже вытаскивать инфу из коллекции если это допустим айдишник в пределах простых чисел или т.п.